# Are these vector iteration forms the same?

Tags: c++, vector, iteration

[Form 1](http://cpp.sh/3td6):

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};   

    for(auto i = array.begin(); i != array.end();) {      
        if(*i == 2 || *i == 5) {
            i = array.erase(i);
        } else {          
            i++;
        }
    }   
}
```

[Form 2](http://cpp.sh/7kjaq):

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};   

    for(auto i = array.begin(); i != array.end(); i++) {
        if(*i == 2 || *i == 5) {
            i-- = array.erase(i);
        }
    }   
}
```

Are these two form identical? Could I go into problems using one or another? (i.e. with every kind of object, such as linked list?).

Comment: Personally I would write neither of these, I would use a while() rather than a for without the last condition. I think they are identical btw.

Comment: This is opinion based, there is a std algorithm [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to do this

Comment: @BlueTrin: How would you write the same while?

Comment: @RichardHodges: no, I'm deciding which kind of iterators use in my plugin...

Comment: I don't think this is opinion based.  I pretty sure one is wrong!

Comment: @RichardHodges: sorry? I don't understand what you mean!

Comment: Form2 does not work, if it supposed to remove 2 and 5 from a vector. The actual resulting vector is 2 3 5.

Comment: Apart from the fact that it doesn't even work in this example, Form 2 definitely won't work with a std::forward_list.

Comment: Form 2 is UB actually, because `i` gets invalidated by `array.erase`. The copy returned by `i--` gets assigned a valid iterator, but it is a temporary that gets destroyed, leaving `i` invalid.

Comment: @SSJ_GZ: why it won't work with a forward_list?

Comment: @markzzz: Because its iterators only move forward (hence the name), so no `i--`.

Comment: @markzzz A forward_list's iterator has no operator--() (nor operator--(int)).

Comment: While I'm at it ;) - I believe it is *permissible* for a vector::iterator to be just a plain old T*: on such an implementation, this won't compile (i-- = ... would be assignment to an rvalue).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: aren't iterators just pointers? I guess they can move whatever I want. Why should I have this constraint to move only ++ and not --?

Comment: @markzzz: Pointers are one type of iterator, but not all iterators are pointers. `forward_list` iterators certainly are not. And the reason for the constraint is because `forward_list` is a singly linked list. The nodes only contain pointers to the next node, not the previous. Which might be important to you if you are under some memory constraint.

Comment: The "which would you use" text is a red-flag for "primarily opinion based", but in this case @EdChum , there is very little opinion involved: one of the options is unambiguously wrong, and one is right.

Comment: @MartinBonner Then the OP needs to rephrase the question and title, the fact that one form is erroneous is irrelevant, the OP didn't ask why one works and the other doesn't, they're soliciting opinion as to which the community prefers

Comment: The main part of the question is "are they the same?"  "Which is better" is very much subsidiary (and I have removed it).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: so forward_list use forward iterators and simple array (or vector) random access iterators?

Comment: @EdChum "Are these vector iteration forms the same?" is absolutely not "opinion based". It is a true/false question.Or has the question been edited since it was closed off?

Comment: @RichardHodges see the edit history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Form 2** is broken.

```
i-- = array.erase(i);
```

Let's break that down;

```
i--
```

This returns a copy of `i`, and then decrements `i`.

```
array.erase(i)
```

This erases the element at `i`, and then returns the iterator to the element after.

```
(i--) = (array.erase(i));
```

This assigns the result of `array.erase(i)` to the copy returned by `i--`.

There is an additional complication in that certainly prior to C++11, you don't know whether the decrement was done before or after the call to `array.erase(i)`, and that would have been undefined behaviour.  Experimentally, GCC does the decrement *before* the erase, so you end up erasing the wrong element.

It may help to write the (nearly) equivalent code out:

```
    auto j = i;
    --i;          // Here??
    auto k = array.erase(i);
    --i;          // Or here?
    j = k;
```

If you want to do this, write it as:

```
    const auto j = i;
    --i;
    array.erase(j);
```

Which makes it much clearer what you are doing.

Comment: But that doesn't say how the value computation of the left and right operands are sequenced.  (My point being that the assignment is to a temporary which is thrown away.)

Comment: I think this is all covered by 1.9/15: *"Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced. [...] The value computations of the operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of the result of the operator. If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined."*

Comment: Oh right.  So it still is undefined behaviour!

Comment: Edit your answer to indicate that this is undefined behaviour

Answer (score 4):

this one, form 3:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    auto is_2_or_5 = [](int i) {
        return i == 2 || i == 5;
    };

    array.erase(std::remove_if(array.begin(),
                               array.end(),
                               is_2_or_5),
                array.end());

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
i-- = array.erase(i);
```

Is undefined behavior both in pre `C++11` and `C++11`.

For more gory details check out:

- [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)
- [Unsequenced value computations (a.k.a sequence points)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852768/unsequenced-value-computations-a-k-a-sequence-points/3852774#3852774)
- especially this: [Order of evaluation and undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17400137/order-of-evaluation-and-undefined-behaviour)

Even if it was well defined I wouldn't use the `i--` construct for anything else than a standalone expression. It is difficult to understand what's happening.